# custom grant permissions page

Tags: permissions, custom

I was asked to investigate if a custom "Grant Permissions" page can be built in Sharepoint 2010. It should:

1. Allow admin to set users for each group (visitors/members/owners) in one page. Currently such page comes up only on creating a site with unique permissions. But the planned custom page should be accessible for each list type too.

2.Inheritance should be broken by default. (Can be handled using Server Object Model?)

Please let me know if it's achievable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's achievable with custom development. Both the Vistors/Members/Owners groups and inheritance can be set through code. You want use:

[SPWeb.BreakRoleInheritance();](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee550474.aspx)  and [SPWeb.CreateDefaultAssociatedGroups()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.createdefaultassociatedgroups.aspx), and then add the users/groups you need to to those roles.

Note that the second method has a bug, and doesn't create the visitors group correctly. There is a [fix (and good example of part of what you're trying to do) here](http://blog.ray1.net/2010/03/bug-in-spweb-createdefaultassociatedgro.html).

I did a similar thing in SharePoint 2007. See http://www.novolocus.com/2009/09/16/how-i-simplified-the-users-and-group-ui-intro/ for information on building the UI.